# Using "OR" Logical Operator For Comparing Strings

Tags: excel, vba

```
For i = Last To 2 Step -1
    If Not (Cells(i, "A").Value) Like "*exe" Or (Cells(i, "A").Value) Like "*dll" Or (Cells(i, "A").Value) Like "*ocx" Then
        Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i
```

Hi everyone, I'm a little new to VBA and was wondering if I could get some assistance. What I'm trying to do here is delete any rows that don't end with "exe", "dll", or "ocx". Executing this as is, it will delete all rows that don't end with "exe". Not sure if I'm using the right syntax in this case. I'd already tried searching the forum like I usually do but I'm stumped this time ... would appreciate any help and apologies if this has been asked before. Thanks!

Comment: Wrap everything after `Not` in parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think you just got your parentheses a little mixed up. You just need one enclosing the whole clause after the Not.

```
For i = Last To 2 Step -1
    If Not (Cells(i, "A").Value Like "*exe" Or Cells(i, "A").Value Like "*dll" Or Cells(i, "A").Value Like "*ocx") Then
        Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Just kidding this works. +1. (I was testing with no value for `Last` doh).

Comment: @dwirony - thanks, if it's easy to do I tend to check code as never 100% sure it will work. And those Not/Or/And questions make my head hurt.